# Lightswitch Grid where columns are defined at Runtime

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a table of Meters. And then a table of Meter Readings (which has a reference to the Meter table, as well as a column for Date and a column for the reading value). The idea being that for each day one would record the reading for a given meter. Using a List and Details screen, I can select a meter in the List section, and then the details section displays the Readings associated with the selected Meter.
So to add a new day's Readings, the user would select a Meter, and then in the New Row of the Readings Grid, enter the new date and reading.
However, what I would like to achieve is the following:
To have a grid, where each row represents a day, and where each column represents a Meter.
That way it will make for quicker user entry to add a new day, and then going across the columns, enter the day's reading for each Meter.
Is this possible in Lightswitch?  Any pointers as to a good approach for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's possible with a custom control. I have build something similar for visualizing room reservations. Basically, it's quite similar to your setup: you have a parent child relationship where in the child table you have "time-line field".
You can find more details here: http://blog.pragmaswitch.com/?p=318
Of course, it's not exactly what you want, but I hope it can give you kind of direction.